# How to check, if row to pushed is already present in 2D vector in c++

Tags: c++, recursion, data-structures, time-complexity, combinations

I am solving a question on Leetcode (combinatins sum 2), where I have to output all the unique combinations such that the sum of the numbers in combination equals target which is already given in question.
[snapshot of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92hC6.png)

I am storing all the correct combinations in a 2D vector, but it says all the combinations must be unique.
for e.g [2,1,5] [2,5,1] [5,2,1] are all same though all are possible answers i should store only one out of them.
To solve this, before I store the combination in 2D vector i am sorting the combination in increasing order.
Now how should i check if that sorted combination is already in the ans matrix or not. I cannot search because it will affect time complexity.

Comment: Perhaps use a different container? Like a set or a map?

Comment: And if the order of the values in each "row" is irrelevant, then sort them to easier check?

Comment: LeetCode is often a better place than Stack Overflow for help on LeetCode problems. If your solution uses backtracking, you don't need to check if a row is already present in a 2D vector. Search this [LeetCode Study Guide](https://leetcode.com/discuss/study-guide/1405817/backtracking-algorithm-problems-to-practice) for the phrase `Combination Sum II` to see how to use backtracking to solve [LeetCode Problem 40. Combination Sum II](https://leetcode.com/problems/combination-sum-ii/description/).

Answer (score 0):

When you are pushing a certain number into your current array, try to use it as many times as you can, and get done with the number.

Start by keeping a track of the original array, and the frequency of each element. Now, you could just sort the initial array, and add the current element as many times to your current state. This makes sure that all combinations are inserted in an always sorted manner - instead of sorting every final output, which would take away a lot of TC. This also ensures no repetitions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).